# Wifi Network connection along side USB tethering

Tags: networking, usb

I am running my Raspberry Pi 2 on a wifi network and also used this article to connect my android phone via USB tethering (for ssh connection):

http://elinux.org/How_to_use_an_Android_tablet_as_a_Raspberry_Pi_console_terminal_and_internet_router

Now the problem is, the wifi router has ip **192.168.0.x** but the USB tethering has **192.168.42.x**

And I can't see a way to connect both at the same time. If I connect my phone then internet is gone :(

Do I have to make some settings on router, phone or Pi?

**Edited**

Here's the `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

#allow-hotplug usb0
#iface usb0 inet dhcp

iface usb0 inet static
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's the result of `top` command http://pastebin.com/QL4Jbi3x

Comment: Can you add the settings at /etc/network/interfaces to your question

Comment: @TolgaVarol Just edited the question

Comment: What do you use wlan0 wlan1 and eth0 for?

Comment: wlan0 has it's connection with my home wifi (192.168.0.x) and other two are not in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you comment out whole the stanzas of `eth0` and `wlan1` since you aren't using them and can you change the stanza of `wlan0` as

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "yourSSID"    #i.e. mine is wpa-ssid "Actual Network"
        wpa-psk "yourPSWRD"    #i.e. mine is wpa-psk "fawfjr21i20"
```

and change usb0 settings as

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

and restart the Pi, also don't forget to comment out `iface usb0 inet static`

**Edit**

USB tethering will always have an IP as 192.168.42.x and according to this post : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46499/how-configure-the-dhcp-settings-of-wifi-tetheringhotspot-in-android

it is hardcoded. But changing that IP address wouldn't mean anything so its not the thing. The thing is connecting to internet from your phone if I didn't misunderstood. I also have a similar problem with my Pi since I have 2 WiFi adaptors, one for WAN and one for local area in AP mode. I suppose the situation is analogue. What you need to do is to bridge those two interfaces wlan0 and usb0. So that when usb0 receives a request it will deliver it to wlan0. For doing that you can check this example :
[bridge eth0 static wlan0 static wlan1 dhcp](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15300/bridge-eth0-static-wlan0-static-wlan1-dhcp)  . Pi should work as a router when a request comes from usb0 interface.

Also this is another guide you might make use of https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Hope this helps. By the way, you only have to make settings on Pi.

Comment: This is strange, but since I made my last changes you mentioned above, my wifi USB adapter isn't working. I tried on my PC too. :/

Comment: Can you type `top` and add the output to your question too and also can you change wlan0's (the one I put above) stanza as I edited now @Rizwan

Comment: Hi @TolgaVarol, just edited the question again and added the result of `top` command. Sorry for late reply, I had to purchase new Wifi Adapter as old one isn't working anymore. And also, I updated `/etc/network/interfaces` but still no good.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, thanks for the edit, I wondered your top output since I thought maybe there was some process which was causing this but after some more search I found that it was not about another process, I'm editing the answer with new findings @Rizwan

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it in the morning. Going to sleep now, it's 2:56 AM here